# Setting content-type for Web API 2 response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm really confused about the most appropriate way to return responses for my RESTful API that I'm building using Web API 2.

At first I made my actions return `IHttpActionResult` and in the method I would use `return Ok()` or `return NotFound()` etc.

Then I found there was no `Forbidden()` so I thought I must be doing things wrong.  So now I'm making my actions return `HttpResponseMessage`.  In my code I'm returning a response by doing the following:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseData));
return response;
```

The problem is, this response now gets sent with the Content-Type "text/plain" - it needs to be sent with the Content-Type of "application/json".  I can't find how I'm supposed to alter the Content-Type of the response, but even if I could it seems cumbersome to do this with every request.  Is the a better way, some sort of best practice that I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of populating it manually, you can do this

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseData);
return response;
```

This, this will return content type as json.

Comment: I wrote my own answer and then realised it was almost identical to yours... Request.CreateResponse does indeed change it from text/plain to application/json (or rather it uses the media formatter). I would add this link where I found the answer: [Action Results in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/action-results)

Answer (score 0):

You can set content negotiation for each request by modifying a collection in global.asax

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the JsonFormatter in your global.asax? For example:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

Another issue which I found is that your routing prefix / route with parameters signature on your Controller cannot be match with the Url you passing in giving usually 404 code.